# How do I filter the task list in Outlook 2010? 

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I filter the tasks in Outlook - just like I would do in Excel.

i.e. Filter by due date, then additional filters which work one on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in `detailed view` or `simple list view` you can right click the subject bar and go to `view settings` where you can determine `groupings`, `sorts` and `filters`

[image]

[image]

and `sort` is probably what you want
[image]